# Filter all instances with high attributes values in Weka

Tags: filter, machine-learning, weka

I've got a dataset of words and their frequencies.

I want to filter all the instances that have got 1 or more attributes whose value is > 200 (for example).

I need something like `RemoveWithValues` filter, but I want to use it for all the attributes and not for only one attribute.

How can I do that?

**Note:** I'm using Weka Explorer, I'm not writing code.

Answer (score 0):

The RemoveWithValues() filter can be used in the following way:

```
Instances data;
RemoveWithValues filter = new RemoveWithValues();

String[] options = new String[4];
options[0] = "-C";   // Choose attribute to be used for selection
options[1] = "1"; // Attribute number    
options[2] = "-S";   // Numeric value to be used for selection on numeric attribute. Instances with values smaller than given value will be selected. (default 0)
options[3] = "10";   //200. Say you want all those instances whose values for this attribute are less than 200
filter.setOptions(options);

filter.setInputFormat(data);
Instances newData = Filter.useFilter(data, filter);
```

So, this is for one single attribute. Put it in a loop, change option[1] in each iteration (iterate up to all of your attribute's indices). In this loop, you have to replace data with newData.

Answer (score 0):

**From the Weka Explorer, the RemoveWithValues Filter could be used as shown below:**

- Enter the Attribute Index as the First Element that needs to be filtered
- Invert the Selection if you wish to keep only the records below 200
- Enter the Split Point of 200.0
- Apply these Changes, then adjust the attribute index for as many attributes are required.

[image: Remove With Values Image]

Failing this option from Weka, you could pre-process your data using tools of the spreadsheet/database where the data is stored.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm looking for a way to do that without having to repeat the same procedure for each attribute (since I've got thousands of attributes).

Comment: Hi Kurt, did you try my solution?

Comment: It would be nice if Weka had the option for attributeIndex of 'first-last', but it doesn't appear to work this way (single attribute only).  Perhaps pre-processing your data by code (see Rushdi's answer) or your favourite spreadsheet/database (wherever your data comes from) may be a better option for filtering all attributes to a desired range.